# Bash - autocomplete .bat file

Tags: bash

I'm working with MINGW Bash on Windows and run .bat files. My problem is when I type `./<tab><tab>` only .sh files are autocompleted. Is there a way to autocomplete all `.bat` files ?

Comment: Did  you `$ chmod 755 file_name.bat` ? If not, try do so... Expect to find Linux-like requirements in cygwin  and its derivatives (which is what MINGW is).

Comment: is the language in the files linux shellscripts (sh/bash/ksh/csh/zsh/etc) or batch (windows CMD commands)?

Comment: I don't know if it's doable with MINGW, but you can always use clink for completion suitable for Windows executables.

Comment: Looking at this I assume not: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/bugs/1902/

Comment: 1) it's bash
2) chmod doesnt work for the x flag. is does not change the flag even on .sh files
3) you can execute bat files, the only thing is that the bash can not autocomplete the file name when there is no `#!/bin/bash` on the first line